# Can someone visit the Schengen Area(Germany) with a "leave to enter" residence permit for the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, germany

My husband a non-EU passport holder (Armenia) and I an EU passport holder (UK) wish to go to Germany. I would like to know if he needs a Schengen visa to go to Germany or is there no need?

He has a "leave to enter" residence card for the UK, as well as this my name is written in his Armenian passport and our relationship (Wife).

Comment: For now, are you interested in just visiting or immediately relocating?

Comment: visiting - I would like to just know if he needs a visa or not? Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Related [Can you enter the Schengen area with a UK visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77159/can-you-enter-the-schengen-area-with-a-uk-visa)

Answer (score 1):

Yes he needs a visa, but it should be issued free of charge as long as the UK remains in the EU.  The residence permit you describe does not count as an "article 10" card.  See [Travel documents for non-EU family members](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm).