# can a non EEA / EU citizen with a current, valid right to work uk visa enter schengen countries for holiday?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, schengen-visas

is it currently possible to enter sweden for a non EU / EEA citizen with a UK work permit visa? this is for a short holiday.

edit: the type of visa is a work permit / residence visa, *not* a temporary visa as referenced in other questions. i.e. the person is living and working in the uk, and has a visa sponsored by their employer in the UK

Comment: What is your nationality? That is what matters, not your residence status in the UK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you enter the Schengen area with a UK visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77159/can-you-enter-the-schengen-area-with-a-uk-visa) You asked the same question yesterday https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161392/travel-to-sweden-for-non-eu-eea-citizen-with-uk-visa If the suggested duplicate doesn’t tell you what you want to know (particularly the second answer), please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: If you have a **UK work permit**, you can't be a UK-Citizen - so the tag is misleading.

Comment: See https://www.government.se/government-policy/migration-and-asylum/list-of-foreign-citizens-who-require-visa-for-entry-into-sweden/  for the list of countries whose citizens require a visa to enter Sweden. A UK work permit in itself does not confer the right to enter *any* Schengen country. See also https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Visiting-Sweden/Nyheter/2020-11-18-Limited-possibilities-of-obtaining-a-visa-to-Sweden.html regarding the likelihood of visa refusal due to Covid restrictions

Comment: The type of UK visa is irrelevant. No UK visa, whether short-term or long-term, confers an exemption from the requirement to have a Schengen visa.

Comment: *Currently* the UK work permit is actually relevant, at least if it means that the person is also resident in the UK. Sweden is currently only allowing persons from (citizens and residents) EEA/Schengen/UK/Switzerland and a handful other country to enter as tourists. Even if in this case a Schengen visa may be required in addition, being resident of the UK may also be an essential requirement.

Comment: The Schengen Area COVID-19 specific Travel restrictions are based on **place of residence**. Your UK **residence permit** proves your place of residence. You must **also** fulfill the Immigration requirements, that are based on your citizenship (Visa required: yes/no). These are **two separate** conditions that must be fulfilled.

Comment: Are you married to an EU citizen? _That_ would be relevant.

Comment: Someone has voted to reopen this question: why?  I voted to close it, but I might be convinced to vote to reopen it if there's some argument in favor that I haven't thought of.

Comment: @phoog Unless the OP clarifies that this question is **not** about immigration, but about residence requirements for coronavirus specific entry conditions, then this question should remain closed.